# AngularJS Routing - Understanding what I'm missing

Tags: angularjs

So I've been going through a demo, and I believe I have it correct, but I'm not sure what I might be missing.

I am getting an error in the angular file.  Is there something that I'm missing, I also don't understand all the pieces here exactly.  I didn't create the template pages yet will that error it out?  I don't specifically understand the controller part of this as I'm routing to pages and on the template I was thinking of creating the calls for the data objects, but maybe it's all supposed to be done here.

```
 var supplychain = angular.module('sc411', ['ngRoute',  'sc411Controllers']);


supplychain.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'contact.html',
        controller: 'contactCtrl'
      }).
      when('/industries', {
        templateUrl: 'industries.html',
        controller: 'industriesCtrl'
      }).
      when('/services', {
        templateUrl: 'services.html',
        controller: 'servicesCtrl'
      }).
      when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);



/* Controllers */

var sc411Controllers = angular.module('sc411Controllers', []);

sc411Controllers.controller('servicesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

}]);

sc411Controllers.controller('aboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {

}]);
```

Comment: if the controllers and templates you set in the router aren't defined and known by angular, you will get an error.  First try just making 1 route and defining the controller and template.

Comment: What is the exact error your getting? Can you grab it from the console?

Comment: do check these things, 1. Have you loaded `angular-route.js` after `angular.js`? 2. does `angular-route.js` & `angular.js` has same file version.?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=sc411&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)

Comment: Is the main cdn library file include everything?

Comment: I figured it out I need all these files..

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>